# If $H \trianglelefteq G$, then there is a homomorphism $\theta : G / H \rightarrow \text{Aut}(H)$ such that $(G/H) \rtimes_\theta H \cong G$?

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

If $H \trianglelefteq G$, then there is a homomorphism $\theta : G / H \rightarrow \text{Aut}(H)$ such that $(G/H) \rtimes_\theta H \cong G$?

I know that in general $(G/H) \times H \not{\cong} G$ so I was wondering if you can always "recover" the structure lost by quotienting by taking a semidirect product.

This definitely works in some cases (like $D_{2n} / \langle r \rangle \cong C_2$ but if you take the nontrivial homomorphism from $C_n$ to Aut$(C_2)$ you get $C_n \rtimes C_2 \cong D_{2n}$, but can you do this in general? I feel like yes, but I don't know how to approach it.

Comment: No, consider $C_2 \lhd C_4$.

The best you can do is [Schur-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem).

Comment: You've got the notation for semidirect product flipped. Since $H$ is the normal subgroup, it should be $H\rtimes_{\theta}(G/H)$. The way to remember is that the triangle still has the vertex pointing to the normal subgroup, just as in $H\triangleleft G$.